# IOS Landscape Mode not working OPEN GL

Tags: ios, opengl-es-2.0

Ok tried almost everything and it didn't work.

I need my engine to start up in LandscapeRight mode, therefore i call:

```
//
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight animated:NO];
```

The problem is that the rest is not rotated at all,

[image]

I managed to rotate the view by using:

```
[pExternViewController setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI/2.0f)];
```

But it doesn't work as expected, the Frame Buffer size is correct now:

> FrameBuffer: width: 960, height: 640

Still you can see it is not 960x640, and i can't figure out why?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, finally made it.
 [image]

First add this key to your plist file (required)

```
<key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key>
<string>Launch Screen</string>
```

Screen Size definitions

```
#define SCREEN_WIDTH (IOS_VERSION_LOWER_THAN_8 ? (UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait([UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation) ? [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width : [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height) : [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width)

#define SCREEN_HEIGHT (IOS_VERSION_LOWER_THAN_8 ? (UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait([UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation) ? [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height : [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width) : [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height)

#define IOS_VERSION_LOWER_THAN_8 (NSFoundationVersionNumber <= NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_7_1)
```

The window initialization

```
- (void) applicationDidFinishLaunching: (UIApplication*) application
{
    // Start in Landscape
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight animated:NO];

    // Disable Auto Lock screen
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setIdleTimerDisabled: YES];

    // Set Bounds with the proper screen resolution
    CGRect screenBounds = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    screenBounds        = CGRectMake(0, 0, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT);

    // Create window and view controler
    m_window            = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame: screenBounds];
    m_window.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

    // Create new view controller
    pExternViewController        =  [SvgzViewController alloc] ;

    // Initialize view controler with all pointers set up
    if( [pExternViewController initWithFrame: screenBounds ] == nil)
    {
        assert(!"Failed to initialize screen");
        exit(0);
    }

    // Rotate the window
    [m_window setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI/2.0f)];

    // Set the proper window center after transformation
    m_window.center         = CGPointMake(screenBounds.size.height/2, screenBounds.size.width/2);

    // Add GL window
    [m_window addSubview: pExternViewController];

    //
    [m_window makeKeyAndVisible];

}
```

At least no GL side change has to be done by doing it this way.